# Any way for MobX to observe cookies?

Tags: mobx

I'd like to have an autorun (or any sort of reaction) that runs when it notices a cookie change/set. At the moment I'm using an observable boolean that flips when I make a change but it feels a bit messy. Any way to make a cookie observable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote my own package to deal with this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mobx-cookie